# How to combine div display script with php click tracker?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, click

I'm trying to combine a div display javascript with a php tracker that stores the count in mysql db, but I have 0 knowledge of javascript and every answer I've read here has only confused me more.

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showAnswer( whichLayer )
{
 var elem, vis;
 if( document.getElementById ) // this is the way the standards work
 elem = document.getElementById( whichLayer );
 else if( document.all ) // this is the way old msie versions work
 elem = document.all[whichLayer];
 else if( document.layers ) // this is the way nn4 works
 elem = document.layers[whichLayer];
 vis = elem.style;

 // if the style.display value is blank we try to figure it out here
 if(vis.display==''&&elem.offsetWidth!=undefined&&elem.offsetHeight!=undefined)
 vis.display = (elem.offsetWidth!=0&&elem.offsetHeight!=0)?'block':'none';
 vis.display = (vis.display==''||vis.display=='block')?'none':'block';
}
</script>
```

This is my code:

```
<a href="javascript:showAnswer('<?=$link['id_lien']?>')">
```

I created the PHP file logclick.php which will increment my the mysql db.

I need to pass the $link['id_lien'] variable in the javascript, and from what I've understand I can use the $.post but I have no idea where to put it, as it always breaks the code and div no longer displays.

```
  $.post(url, {}, function(r){
  console.log(r);
  });
```

Also - will it count if someone CLOSES the div? I only want it to count on open.

Comment: the above is pure js, when you use $.post are you including the jQuery library?  Also I don't get your last 2 lines of js - you are changing the display to block depending on the width and height but you do the opposite in the line below

Comment: Answer must be "no" as I did not know there was a difference.

Comment: that will be why it is breaking then, if you are using chrome you can press f12 and click on the console tab, it will tell you what js errors are being thrown

Comment: thanks - I debugged the code but how can I pass the variable? Using  $.post(url, {}, function(r){
    console.log(r);
  });

Comment: you pass it thourgh in the `data:` see the examples here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/.  You would need to call this within your showAnswer function and within an if stetment if `vis.display == "block"`

Comment: Can I get a bit more details please? I've been struggling -> I added `data: whichLayer` in the script and `$id = $_POST["whichLayer"]` in the PHP file but $id returns empty

Comment: This is how I've used it in the past: `data: { whichLayer : "value" }` or if I'm doing it in a form.submit I'll do something like this: `$(this).serialize() + '&whichLayer=value'` where `$(this)` is the form

Comment: Hey Pete, thanks for the help! It took a while but I finally got it to pass all the variables as wanted. I ended up simplifying the original function!